# The sum of two dependent gamma random variables

Tags: gamma-distribution

If X∼Gamma(a1,θ1) and Y∼Gamma(a2,θ2), where X and Y are dependent random variables, what is then the way to calculate the expectation of the sum X+Y.

Have searched for it only but cannot figure it out.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity

Answer (score 2):

Expectation is a linear operator hence (Assuming $a$ and $\theta$ are the shape and scale parameters):
$$E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y) = a_1\theta_1 + a_2\theta_2.$$

It is as simple as that: dependency doesn't matter when you are just interested in the expectation of a sum.